# Can I track the progress of my filter function?

Tags: python

I have a rather large list. Most of the elements of the list are not of interest to me, so I'd like to filter it to find the elements I care about. My python code is something like

```
def get_interesting_elements(L)
    return filter(lambda x: my_criteria(x) == True, L)
```

Since my list is long, I'd like to be able to track the progress of my program.

Are there any tools that allow me to do this?

Comment: Just use a normal for loop and a counter variable instead of filter?

Comment: Why not [progressbar](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/progressbar)? @Brian Fitzpatrick

Comment: you could use `enumerate` so you know for what element in the list you are

Comment: `filter(lambda x: my_criteria(x) == True, L)`  probably does nothing else than mere `filter(my_criteria, L)`

Answer (score 3):

```
count = 0
def my_criteria(x):
    global count
    count += 1
    print count+"/"+len(L)
    return True or False
def get_interesting_elements(L)
    return filter(lambda x: my_criteria(x) == True, L)
```

its not very elegant but you get the idea im sure

a slightly more pythonic alternative ...

```
def get_interesting_elems(L):
    for i,ele in enumerate(L):
        if condition(ele): 
           yield ele
        print "%d/%d"%(i,len(L))

result=list(get_interesting_elems(my_list))
```

Comment: Good idea. Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: UnboundLocalError => `global count`

Comment: @kxr i wondered about that ... i thought maybe since it was += instead of an assignment it might work without the global count

Comment: @JoranBeasley, i would optimize the code of 'my_criteria' function so that it doesn't count the length of L every time and i would output percentage and only if it's been changed. For example 1%, 2%, but NO output between 1% and 2%.

Comment: to no have and large amount of print, you can put a condition to print each n elements, where n could be 1000, 10000, etc

Comment: @MaxU ... Lists know their length ... its not calculating it each time

Answer (score 0):

This solution doesn't require to include the progress code into your criteria function and will work with other criteria functions:

```
def show_progress(function, L):
    def wrapper(elem):
        i, x = elem
        print('{}/{}'.format(i, len(L)))
        return function(x)
return wrapper

def get_interesting_elements(L)
    return map(lambda x: x[1], filter(show_progress(my_criteria, L), enumerate(L)))
```

This is rather elaborated though. I would recommend manually filtering the list using a loop.